# How can I stop counting number of clicks when countdown timers stops?

Tags: android, timer

As I am new to the android please help me out .In my App when i click the textbox it starts counting number of clicks and when the textbox is clicked once the countdown timer starts .I want that my counter (mCount) stops when CountDown timer finishes up and i also want that when timer finishes no one can click the textbox means the textbox becomes unclickable until user presses reset button. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code :
TextView tv,t1;

```
Button reset;
private int mCount = 0;
private final long startTime = 5 * 1000;
private final long interval = 1 * 1000;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private boolean timerStarted = false;
private MediaRouteButton textView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_game);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tv  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv.setText("5"); // starting from 5.
    reset=(Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);
    final TextView countTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewCount);
    t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
    t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!timerStarted) {
                countDownTimer.start();
                timerStarted = true;

            }
            mCount++;
            countTextView.setText("SCORE: " + mCount);
        }


    });
 reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent intent = getIntent();
         finish();
         startActivity(intent);
     }
 });

}
public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {

    private TextView mTextField;

    public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {

        super(startTime, interval);

    }

    @Override

    public void onFinish() {



        mTextField.setText("done!");

    }


    @Override

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        tv.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When the timer ends you can use [`View.setClickable(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)) to disable the clicking for the time being:

```
public void onFinish(){
   mTextField.setText("done!");
   t1.setClickable(false);
}
```

You can change the clickable state back whenever it is most convenient to restart the timer.

Comment: I had set android:clickable=true in XML and does what you said in my main_activity.java .When I run this app on my device then it shows your app has Unfortunately crashed after timer stops . Now what to do ?

Comment: @abhisheksharma that depends on what the stack trace was. What caused it to crash?

Answer (score 0):

just maintain flag that will be true on Timer stops and before incrementing counter check that flag is false or not

Comment: public boolean flag=false;   on timestop make it true and before incrementing check if flag is not true